# PIC ADC clock calculation

Tags: pic, microchip, mplab, adc

I have been lately gone into ADC and trying to figure out what is ADC clock why is it useful what is tad, tosc, fosc and those things and how to calculate the ADC clock I have been searching and searching for days and I have read almost all sites available for this topic on internet but I am still small in 8th grade so I cant understand all these hard mathematic operations I would highly appreciate anyone who could explain this to me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`ADC` stands for analogue-to-digital converter - it's how the PIC measures voltages.

`Tosc` is the *period* of the oscillator (clock) and it is equal to `1/Fosc`, where `Fosc` is the *frequency* of the oscillator (clock). If your clock is 1 MHz, then `Fosc` = 1 MHz (1000000 Hz) and `Tosc` is 0.000001 seconds (1 µs or micro-second).

Comment: ok paul I understand till here so how to calculate the adc clock and tad with Fosc*2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 what are these values and which to choose this is the part I really don't understand and thanks so much for taking some of your time and effort to explain this to me

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know much about the PIC - I just covered the basics above, which are common to most micro-controllers. It sounds though as if you get to configure how often the ADC measures a value, and what you set this to will depend on what you're measuring. All I can suggest is Googling for "PIC ADC example code" or similar, to see how other people set up the ADC and measure stuff with it. Good luck!